# TThread.OnTerminate executing thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, tthread

The Delphi help for `TThread.OnTerminate` states that:

> The method assigned to the OnTerminate event is executed in the context of the main thread rather than the context of the thread being terminated.

Is this even the case when the thread is created in another thread than the main thread?

So, is the `OnTerminate` called in the thread that created the `TThread`, or is it called in main thread? The IDE does not tells me this. When I debug, I see no active thread in the `OnTerminate` event. :-/

Comment: It's actually possible to see a thread's ID in the IDE when debugging. The **Call Stack**, **Watch List**, and **Local Variables** panels all display the current thread ID. I just tried to add a breakpoint in a thread's `OnTerminate` handler and can see that its thread ID is 12888. And if I put a breakpoint in some GUI code (like a button's `OnClick` handler, the main form's `OnCreate` handler, a menu item handler etc.) I see that the main GUI thread is 12888. My conclusion is therefore, ... Well, I think you can guess it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is correct.  The `OnTerminate` event handler is always run in the main thread by default.  Internally, `TThread.DoTerminate()` (which is called after the thread's `Execute()` method exits) uses `TThread.Synchronize()` to call the handler:

```pascal
function ThreadProc(Thread: TThread): Integer;
var
  ...
begin
  ...
  try
    if not Thread.Terminated then
    try
      Thread.Execute;
    except
      ...
    end;
  finally
    ...
    Thread.DoTerminate;
    ...
  end;
end;

procedure TThread.DoTerminate;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnTerminate) then Synchronize(CallOnTerminate);
end;

procedure TThread.CallOnTerminate;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnTerminate) then FOnTerminate(Self);
end;
```

If you want the `OnTerminate` handler to run in the context of the terminating thread (or any other thread you want), you can simply override `DoTerminate()` to call the handler however you want, eg:

```pascal
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
    ...
  protected
    ...
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure DoTerminate; override;
    ...
  end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  ...
end;

procedure TMyThread.DoTerminate;
begin
  // do whatever you want here, but DON'T call inherited!
  if Assigned(OnTerminate) then OnTerminate(Self);
end;
```